# How to Put image inside another image view

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

i want to put sticker view completely inside the image view( it should not go out of image boundary)

image view is uploaded by user so it cannot be a fixed size.I can do adjustments on sticker size if needed current sticker size (540x670)
[image: sticker should not be visible on background of image(darkblue)]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">

      <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativemain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue_900"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <com.A.B.C.StickerView.StickerView
            android:id="@+id/stickerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow completely. Which image needs to go over which one? Anyway, basic idea is to use a `FrameLayout` that will wrap the `ImageView` and then add the second one inside it.

Comment: grey image (sticker view) should be visible inside image view(sea image).The white portion marked in image should be invisible.

Comment: Yeah, okay that's clearer now. Just create a container layout like `FrameLayout` that'll be exactly the size of the image (`wrap_content`) and then add the `StickerView` inside that

Comment: which layout should be replaced with FrameLayout (Relative or Linear)

Comment: it worked thanks(plz post it as answer so i can accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment helped solve, I'll just post in the answer then.

> Just create a container layout like `FrameLayout` that'll be exactly the size of the image (`wrap_content`) and then add the `StickerView` inside that.

Something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue_900"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <com.A.B.C.StickerView.StickerView
        android:id="@+id/stickerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using constraint layout and set the constraints of the sticker to the inner of the image view.